# One number divisible by all prime factors of another?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers

Given two numbers $x$ and $y$, how to check whether $x$ is divisible by **all** prime factors of $y$ or not?, is there a way to do this without factoring $y$?.

Comment: You could factorize the GCD. :)

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math Stack Exchange! To get the best answers, it is necessary to include your attempt at the problem. You can edit your post to add your ideas.

Comment: Have you heard of Euclidean algorithm? The final remainder obtained is the GCD. Say if the remainder is 1, both numbers are co-prime and  thus one number is not divisible by all prime factors of another. When the final remainder is larger than 1, they have certain GCD. If the GCD equals to the smaller number, your statement is valid, and vice versa.
The advantage of this method is that no factorizations but subtractions and multiplications are done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $x$ is divisible by all the prime factors of $y$, then so is the highest common factor $h_1$ of $x$ and $y$.

To test whether $y$ has a prime factor $p$ which is not a factor of $x$ - well then $p$ is not a factor of $h_1$, but will be a factor of $y_1$ where $y=y_1h_1$. Let $h_2$ be the highest common factor of $h_1$ and $y_1$ and $y_1=h_2y_2$. Then $y_2$ will retain any prime factor $p$ which is not a factor of $x$, and this will not be a factor of $h_2$.

The $h_i$ are decreasing positive integers, so the process terminates. If some $h_i=1$ with $y_i\gt 1$ then $y$ has a prime factor which $x$ does not. Otherwise all the prime factors of $y$ must also be prime factors of $y$.

---

To illustrate with $x=168, y=132$ we have $h_1=12, y_1=11$ and $h_2=1, y_2=11$ detects a problem.

With $x=168, y=98$ we have $h_1=14, y_1=7$ and then $h_2=7, y_2=1$ and $h_3=1, y_3=1$ and all the prime factors of $y$ are factors of $x$.

Note the hcf can be determines by the Euclidean algorithm, without factoring $y$.

Answer (score 5):

$x$ is divisible by all prime factors of $y$ if and only if for some $n$, $x^n\equiv0$ modulo $y$. You might compute $x^n$ modulo $y$ for $n=1$ up to say $\log_2(y)$ and see if $0$ arises as a result. For large numbers, where prime factorization is hard, but modular arithmetic is doable, this would be more efficient than prime factorization. I say $\log_2(y)$ because that is an upper bound for any exponent on a prime factor of $y$ in the prime factorization of $y$. So by the time you have raised $x$ to that power, any prime factor of $x$ will then be raised to a power at least as large as it could arise in the prime factorization of $y$.

@Joffan points out in the comments that you could skip to just raising to the $\log_2(y)$ power. If you use repeated squaring, it does speed things up to $\log_2\log_2(y)$ multiplications modulo $y$. In fact, raising even higher to the next power of $2$ saves a step or two here and there.

Applied to Mark's examples, this process would go like this:
$$\begin{align}
x=168,y=132&\rightarrow \lfloor\log_2(y)\rfloor=7\rightarrow\text{8 is the next power of 2}\\
&\phantom{\rightarrow \lfloor\log_2(y)\rfloor=7\rightarrow}\text{Explicitly,  $8=2^{\lceil\log_2{ \lfloor\log_2(y)\rfloor}\rceil}$}\\
&\rightarrow 168^8=((168^2)^2)^2\\
&\rightarrow 168^8\equiv(108^2)^2\\
&\rightarrow 168^7\equiv72^2\\
&\rightarrow 168^7\equiv144\\
\end{align}$$
which uses three squarings mod $y$ to determine the answer is no. And$$\begin{align}
x=168,y=98&\rightarrow \lfloor\log_2(y)\rfloor=6\rightarrow\text{8 is the next power of 2}\\
&\rightarrow 168^8=((168^2)^2)^2\\
&\rightarrow 168^8=(0^2)^2\\
&\rightarrow 168^8=0^2\\
&\rightarrow 168^8\equiv0\\
\end{align}$$
which technically uses three squarings if we don't see the early $0$ to determine the answer is yes. (Or you could make the algorithm check each step to see if there are early zeros if you like---not much time saved though by preventing a few calculations of $0^2$.)

Comment: Although my answer gives a practical computation in this case, the idea here is the one which is easiest to use in general or in abstract cases. The idea of having to take the power of some entity like $x$ to make it a multiple of $y$ is captured in advanced uses of the word "radical" (a generalisation of taking the $n^{th}$ root). The key idea is well illustrated by this specific case, and the example is well worth remembering for future use.

Comment: Note that you don't need to compute all intermediate powers; computing any power at or above the limit case gives you the answer, and since you would typically be using a squaring process, you only need $\log_2 \log_2 y$ squaring steps to verify.

Comment: @Joffan Thanks, I added that to the answer.

Comment: ... and in both those cases, you can just check the power of 2 exponent above, so no detailed multiplications between squares required - just run squaring out to $x^8$.

Comment: Thanks! I was editing that right after I pinged you :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a pretty simple algorithm based on gcd.

1. $c := \gcd(x,y)$.
2. $z := y / c$.
3. If $z = 1$, terminate.  All prime factors in y were also in $x$.
4. $c := \gcd(x,z)$.
5. If $c = 1$, terminate.  $z > 1$ and $z$ divides $y$, but no prime factor of $z$ divides $x$.
6. $z := z / c$.
7. Goto 3.  $z$ dimnishes every iteration, so we're guaranteed to terminate.